# Captive Portal Browser Close After Authentication

Tags: android, ios, laravel, networking, captiveportal

I have configured the captive portal on TP-Link EAP 225 with an external authentication portal and radius server. The external captive portal authentication web page is built in Laravel. It seems to be working fine on most of the devices and results are expected. What we do is redirect the user to a specific page after authentication.

The issue is on some android devices when devices detect captive portal it opens a captive browser (default captive browser) and it closed immediately after the authentication is passed.

I want a solution to handle it, either detect captive portal browser using JS and ask the user to open it in OS default browser, like Chrome and Safari, or keep the captive browser open after authentication and redirect the user to redirect-page.

I have searched on google and find some discussion regarding this issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933146/prevent-captive-portal-auto-close-after-authentication-android) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950326/is-it-possible-to-detect-the-android-captive-portal-browser) but these discussions are quite old and nowadays android has new versions where these solutions seem to be not working.

Anyone who has worked on it please share your experience. Expert opinion is required in this matter.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You may have better luck on Server Fault with this, as it's leaning a little more toward network administration.  Take a look at https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic before posting there to ensure your post is on topic.

Comment: My issue is different here. We are able to open our custom captive page in Android but we are struggling to close the page using JS. When we try redirect our page using  window.location="captiveurl" it works sometimes (return 204) and breaks some times (returns 200) response.